# Java JCEKS Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jceks

OS Solaris 10.

I have java 8 and IBM  MQ 8.0.0.5 installed on my machine.
I have defined one svrconn connection and I also have a java client.
I am trying to enable SSL authentication between java client and IBM MQ server but I am getting below error :

```
JMSCC0001.FDC PID:16798

JMS Common Client First Failure Symptom Report


Product          :- IBM WebSphere MQ classes for JMS
Date/Time        :- Wed Aug 28 09:24:59 GMT 2019
System time      :- 1566984299972
Operating System :- SunOS
UserID           :- root
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 25.191-b12

Source Class     :- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection
Source Method    :- getNonFipsSocketFactory()
ProbeID          :- 03
Thread           :- name=xxx priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6e0be858

                                      Data
                                      ----

|   Description        :-  Cannot open keystore file
|   Exception message  :-  Invalid keystore format

                              Version information
                              -------------------

IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
8.0.0.5
p800-005-160516.2
Production
Component Title: IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
Component Name:  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
Version:         8.0.0.5
Class Name:      class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
CMVC:            p800-005-160516.2
Jar location:    file:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar
Factory Class:   class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
```

I can run /opt/mqm/bin/runmqckm utility to list all the certificate stored in keystore but java client is still throwing error.

Comment: How do you provide the key store name to the java app?  What is the full `runmqckm` you use to view the contents?

Comment: From what I know, your keystore need to be a jks for the java client, not for the MQ server. Are you sure the client keystore is indeed a jks ? One of the easiest way to test it is to try to use MQExplorer as your Java Client.

Comment: ERR JMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'xxxxx' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'. 
 Thu Aug 29 05:14:26 2019 ERR Ops!com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager xxxx with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'. 
 Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode,

Comment: when I set TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as ciphersuit and cipherspec ,I get above error in java client log. 
 If while starting java client ,I put -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false as JVM argument then FFDC file is created stating invalid keystore so I removed that line and started java client but again I received above error. 

 So should I set -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false as jvm argument or not ? 
 I used TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as well as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA but both doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Yes I am using JCEKS as keystore  and use /opt/mqm/bin/runmqckm  -cert -list -db  key.jck -type jceks -pw xxxx to see the contents

Comment: Why are you using a JCEKS keystore and not a JKS keystore?

Comment: I am using "runmqckm -keydb -create -db key.jck -pw xxxxx -type jceks" to create keystore. The same thing was working till IBM MQ 7.5 but after upgrading to 8.0.0.5,it's throwing error.

Comment: Try with a jks instead.

Comment: `com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` is required if you are not using a IBM java.

Comment: created jks format as well but still getting the same error

Comment: Not clear what error you got or what settings you had for the last round.

Comment: UserID           :- root
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 25.191-b12

Source Class     :- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection
Source Method    :- getNonFipsSocketFactory()
ProbeID          :- 03
Thread           :- name=xxxx priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6e0be858

                                      Data
                                      ----

|   Description        :-  Cannot open keystore file
|   Exception message  :-  Invalid keystore format

Comment: getting invalid keystore format.I tried with JKS as well as JCEKS  keystore but both the time same error at java client side. I am using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as sslciphersuit/sslcipher .I used /opt/mqm/bin/runmqckm and oracle java 8 to create keystore.

Comment: 1. runmqckm -keydb -create -db key.jck -pw xxx -type JKS 

no issue here. 

 2. runmqckm -cert -export -db /mqDir/key.kdb -pw xxx -label javaclient -target key.jck -target_pw xxx -type JKS 

An IO Exception has occurred: 

 Invalid keystore format .    Correct command to export certificate would be runmqckm -cert -export -db /mqDir/key.kdb -type CMS -pw xxx -label javaclient -target key.jck -target_pw xxx -target-type JKS